# JavaScript split window.location.hash

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var fullHash = window.location.hash;
// fullHash = #search?t=operator&q=Velvet
```

I need to split the fullHash variable into 3 separate values. One value needs to say 'search', another should say 'operator', and the last should say 'Velvet'. I have tried multiple regex style splits but can't figure it out. If anyone could help me write this I would highly appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple solution:

```
var fullHash = window.location.hash;
    fullHash.match(/\w{3,}/g);
```

Results in:

```
["search", "operator", "Velvet"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this **regex** ([demo](http://rubular.com/r/yt9ZdHG89B))

```
#(\w+)\?t=(\w+)&q=(\w+)
```

Comment: Would it be written like: fullHash.split("/#(\w+)\?t=(\w+)&q=(\w+)/")

Comment: `fullHash.split(/#(\w+)\?t=(\w+)&q=(\w+)/)`

Comment: The array has two empty leading and trailing strings: ["", "search", "operator", "Velvet", ""]

Answer (score 0):

```
var fullHash = '#search?t=operator&q=Velvet';
fullHash.match(/[#=][^#=?&]*/g).map(function(m) {
    return m.substr(1);
})
// => ["search", "operator", "Velvet"]
```